# Adding borders to dynamic range SQL query using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have tried a bunch of different ideas, and I'm still stuck. I'm new to VBA, so I can't figure out how to get exactly what I need, because I don't totally understand the language.

I'm looking to add borders (both outer and inner) around each cell in the data that is returned to the query. How can I write this into the code? I'm going to attach a picture of what the user will hopefully see as well.

Here's what I have:

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim WSP1 As Worksheet
Set con = New ADODB.Connection
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.StatusBar = "Contacting SQL Server..."

' Remove any values in the cells where we want to put our Stored Procedure's results.
Dim rngRange As Range
Set rngRange = Range(Cells(8, 2), Cells(Rows.Count, 1)).EntireRow
rngRange.ClearContents

' Log into our SQL Server, and run the Stored Procedure
con.Open "Provider=XXXXXXetc"

' Set up the parameter for our Stored Procedure
' (Parameter types can be adVarChar,adDate,adInteger)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("Assembly", adVarChar, adParamInput, 10, Range("B1").Text)

Application.StatusBar = "Running stored procedure..."
cmd.CommandText = "Custom.PRO_BOM_XXXX"
Set rs = cmd.Execute(, , adCmdStoredProc)

' Copy the results to cell B7 on the first Worksheet
Set WSP1 = Worksheets(1)
WSP1.Activate
If rs.EOF = False Then WSP1.Cells(8, 2).CopyFromRecordset rs

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set cmd = Nothing

con.Close
Set con = Nothing

Application.StatusBar = "Data successfully updated."





End Sub
```

Current Outcome:

[image: Current Outcome]

Expected Outcome:

[image: Expected Outcome]

Comment: I removed the sql and sql server tags as this has nothing to do with databases. This is all going to be from your application code.

Comment: Am I able to add a code to include the border in this code though? I'm trying to get all this to happen from one click of the refresh button.

Comment: Does this work for you? `If rs.EOF = False Then WSP1.Cells(8, 2).CopyFromRecordset rs
WSP1.Cells(8, 2).CurrentRegion.Borders.Color = vbBlack`

Comment: Unfortunately no, I get "Application-defined or object-defined error"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want something like:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim con As ADODB.Connection
    Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim WSP1 As Worksheet
    Set con = New ADODB.Connection
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.StatusBar = "Contacting SQL Server..."

    ' Remove any values in the cells where we want to put our Stored Procedure's results.
    Dim rngRange As Range
    Set rngRange = Range(Cells(8, 2), Cells(Rows.Count, 1)).EntireRow
    rngRange.ClearContents

    ' Log into our SQL Server, and run the Stored Procedure
    con.Open "Provider=XXXXXXetc"

    ' Set up the parameter for our Stored Procedure
    ' (Parameter types can be adVarChar,adDate,adInteger)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("Assembly", adVarChar, adParamInput, 10, Range("B1").Text)

    Application.StatusBar = "Running stored procedure..."
    cmd.CommandText = "Custom.PRO_BOM_XXXX"
    Set rs = cmd.Execute(, , adCmdStoredProc)

    ' Copy the results to cell B7 on the first Worksheet
    Set WSP1 = Worksheets(1)
    '
    If rs.EOF then
        Application.StatusBar = ""
        GoTo Closedown
    End If
    Dim NumRows As Integer, EndRow As Integer, EndCol As Integer
    EndCol = 12 ' You can adjust this
    NumRows = rs.RecordCount
    EndRow = 7 + NumRows ' - Adjust the number 7 if you ever decide to start pasting from 8
    ' Do the paste
    WSP1.Cells(8, 2).CopyFromRecordset rs
    ' Now set the range:
    Dim PastedRange As Range
    With WSP1
        Set PastedRange = .Range(.Cells(8, 2), .Cells(EndRow, EndCol))
    End With
    '
    PastedRange.Borders.Color = vbBlack ' Thanks for the tip, sktneer
    '
    Application.StatusBar = "Data successfully updated."
Closedown:
    rs.Close: Set rs = Nothing
    Set cmd = Nothing
    con.Close: Set con = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Looks good! Thank you, I just can't figure out where to put this in my code above, so that it all happens from that first button click. Any ideas?

Comment: I edited it to account for the entire code of your sub. Also, thanks to user sktneer (above comment) for the use or Borders.Color (instead of having to specify all the external and internal borders individually).

Comment: Hi Chris - thank you for all your help. I'll post the code I landed on.

Comment: You're welcome. If you accept my answer then kindly up-vote it and click the green tick - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone for the help. Here's what I contrived for a working solution:

```
Sub Button1_Click()


Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim WSP1 As Worksheet
Set con = New ADODB.Connection
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.StatusBar = "Contacting SQL Server..."
Set WSP1 = Worksheets(1)
WSP1.Activate

' Remove any values in the cells where we want to put our Stored Procedure's results.
Dim rngRange As Range
Set rngRange = Range(Cells(8, 2), Cells(Rows.Count, 1)).EntireRow
rngRange.ClearContents
rngRange.ClearFormats

' Log into our SQL Server, and run the Stored Procedure
con.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=XXXXX;Initial Catalog=XXXXX;Integrated Security=SSPI;Trusted_Connection=Yes"
cmd.ActiveConnection = con

Application.StatusBar = "Running stored procedure..."
cmd.CommandText = "PRO_BOM_XXXXX"
Set rs = con.Execute("Exec Custom.PRO_XXXXX '" & ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Value2 & "','" & ActiveSheet.Range("B2").Value2 & "'")

' Copy the results to cell B7 on the first Worksheet
Set WSP1 = Worksheets(1)
If rs.EOF Then
    Application.StatusBar = ""
    GoTo Closedown
End If
Dim EndCol As Integer
EndCol = 14
WSP1.Cells(8, 2).CopyFromRecordset rs

'find the last row
Dim LastRow As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
' Now set the range:
Dim PastedRange As Range
With WSP1
    Set PastedRange = .Range(.Cells(8, 2), .Cells(LastRow, EndCol))
End With

'Add borders
PastedRange.Borders.Color = vbBlack

Application.StatusBar = "Data successfully updated."


Closedown:
rs.Close: Set rs = Nothing
Set cmd = Nothing
con.Close: Set con = Nothing

End Sub
```